# Widget doesnt build after value of conditional changes in flutter/getx

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

So I have a logincontroller which has the value of isloading and it is initially set to false and is observable.

```
class LoginController extends GetxController {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> loginFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  late TextEditingController emailController, passwordController;
  var isloading = false.obs; <<<<<
```

now in my view file I have:

...

```
  Container(
                      color: Colors.blueGrey,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      height: 150,

                      child: Obx(()=>
                        Center(
                          **child: logincontroller.isloading.value ? CircularProgressIndicator(): Container(child: Text('hello its false'))**,
                             
                            ),
                      )

                    ),
```

now when i press login. the value of isloading is changed to true. however, on the screen the circularprogressindicator widget doesn't show up. Only when I hot reload does it come up.

My question is how Do I rebuild the center widget that contains the ternary operator?

Comment: You should share whatever happens when you press login because your UI code looks fine.

Comment: hey thanks for replying. some one helped me figure it out. basically was missing the '.value' in the login.